# Corda 4.1 : Cross-reference between MappedSchemas

Tags: hibernate, corda

When I'm running the nodes this kind of warning is printed to console: Cross-reference between MappedSchemas `DealSchemaV1` and `CompanySchemaV1`. MappedSchema `DealSchemaV1` entity `PersistentDealState` field `sender` is of type `PersistentCompany` defined in another MappedSchema `CompanySchemaV1`. This may cause issues when evolving MappedSchema or migrating its data, ensure JPA entities are defined within the same enclosing MappedSchema.

If I follow the warning suggestion and place all the entities in one `SchemaV1` there will be hundreds of entities in one schema which is awful.

What is the best practice to resolve this warning?

```
object CompanySchema

object CompanySchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
        schemaFamily = CompanySchema.javaClass,
        version = 1,
        mappedTypes = listOf(...)
) {
    @Embeddable
    class PersistentCompany(   
        ...
    )   
    ...
}
```

```
object DealSchema

object DealSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
        schemaFamily = DealSchema.javaClass,
        version = 1,
        mappedTypes = listOf(...)
) {
    @Entity
    @Table(...)
    class PersistentDealState(

            @Embedded
            var sender: CompanySchemaV1.PersistentCompany?,

            ...
    )
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "class PersistentCompany" and  "class PersistentDealState" in same schema and cross refer each other.

Following is the code for reference that you can use to restructure your code - 
(see url for details - https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/docs/source/api-persistence.rst)

```
@CordaSerializable
object SchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = Schema::class.java, version = 1, mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentParentToken::class.java, PersistentChildToken::class.java)) {

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_data")
class PersistentParentToken(
        @Column(name = "owner")
        var owner: String,

        @Column(name = "issuer")
        var issuer: String,

        @Column(name = "amount")
        var currency: Int,

        @Column(name = "linear_id")
        var linear_id: UUID,

         @JoinColumns(JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"), JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"))

        var listOfPersistentChildTokens: MutableList<PersistentChildToken>
) : PersistentState()

@Entity
@CordaSerializable
@Table(name = "child_data")
class PersistentChildToken(
        @Id
        var Id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

        @Column(name = "owner")
        var owner: String,

        @Column(name = "issuer")
        var issuer: String,

        @Column(name = "amount")
        var currency: Int,

        @Column(name = "linear_id")
        var linear_id: UUID,

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersistentParentToken::class)
        var persistentParentToken: TokenState

) : PersistentState()
```

Hope it resolves your issue